# *.default is not a constructor

Tags: nestjs, web3js, tsconfig

I know there is plenty of topic around this question but I read a lot and I didn't found any answer.

I try to use a 3rd party through NPM in my nodeJS project (nest).
But when it compiles, I have the `*.default is not a constructor` error.

When I go into the source in the node_modules, I see the error.

```
const web3_1 = require("web3");
[...]
const getClient = async (options) => {
    const { url } = options;
    return new web3_1.default(url);
};
```

If I remove the default in here, it's working like a charm, but this is not something I control ...

I put the `esModuleInterop` to true in my tsconfig.json but that's not working.

Here is my tsconfig file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES2018",
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

[According to their docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/getting-started.html) and [their source code](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/1.x/packages/web3/src/index.js) you shouldn't need to use `default`. Just

```js
const web3_1 = require("web3");
[...]
const getClient = async (options) => {
    const { url } = options;
    return new web3_1(url);
};
```

And you should be good. [Looks like they may have their types messed up](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/5076#issuecomment-1140289105) and you'll need to tell Typescript to ignore it

Comment: That's what I think, but the source code is here. https://github.com/owl1n/nestjs-web3/blob/main/src/web3-client.provider.ts#L15
And this is the good way, but when I 'npm install' it, that's what I have. 

And I have another issue now is that I can't use this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/@asset-projects/token-list
because of the 'unexpected token export'

I am kindda new in the tsconfig issues.